# Need Help Accessing ID Property In Complex Array Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filtering

Having issues trying to filter this array by the ID which I am getting from this.match.params object. I am trying match this up with the ID in the array for the review, but I keep getting undefined.

I tried using filter by ID, but this is returning a null match due to probably not filtering the correct object

const id = this.props.match.params === cju980jb901l00740i07skgpc
so THIS id is the one I am trying to filter for, but I can't seem to have access to using array.filter((review => review.id === id)

```
0:
Author: {id: "cju9808n401fo0740rbqgej9p", username: "asdfsd", 
email: "asldkf@gmail.com", __typename: "User"}
ProjectReviewed: {id: "cju980j9a01kd07407qvtwh5o", name: "Amy's 1st 
Project", titleImg: "http://lorempixel.com/400/400/", __typename: 
"Project"}
id: "cju980jb901l00740i07skgpc"
name: "Nice Job!"
text: "I really like how you did this."
timestamp: "2019-04-05T00:00:00.000Z"
__typename: "Review"
__proto__: Object
1: {id: "cju980jcz01l80740jwohw41e", name: "Wicked", text: "You're 
a rockstar!", timestamp: "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z", Author: {…}, 
…}
2: {id: "cju980jdh01lg0740j8o4u60o", name: "Well Done", text: "I'm 
amazed - truly.", timestamp: "2019-03-19T00:00:00.000Z", Author: 
{…}, …}
3: {id: "cju980jdy01lo0740mmo1yfkf", name: "DiS iS TrASSh", text: 
"Thank u, next!", timestamp: "2019-01-12T00:00:00.000Z", Author: 
{…}, …}
4: {id: "cju980jev01lw0740p6k8r7d3", name: "Teach Me How to Do 
This!", text: "Notice me senpai", timestamp: "2019-02- 
19T00:00:00.000Z", Author: {…}, …}
5: {id: "cju980jfs01m40740pe5gxn9a", name: "This is nice", text: 
"...real nice", timestamp: "2019-01-11T00:00:00.000Z", Author: {…}, 
 …}
6: {id: "cju980jge01mc0740mqyu5zi3", name: "Noob", text: "Why are 
you even posting a tutorial about something you know nothing 
about?", timestamp: "2018-07-14T00:00:00.000Z", Author: {…}, …}
7: {id: "cju980jgx01mk0740g1ehxjsf", name: "Wow", text: "You gotta 
create more of these.", timestamp: "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z", 
Author: {…}, …}
8: {id: "cju980jb901l00740i07skgpc", name: "Nice Job!", text: "I 
really like how you did this.", timestamp: "2019-04- 
05T00:00:00.000Z", Author: {…}, …}
9: {id: "cju980jcz01l80740jwohw41e", name: "Wicked", text: "You're 
a rockstar!", timestamp: "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z", Author: {…}, 
…}
10: {id: "cju980jdh01lg0740j8o4u60o", name: "Well Done", text: "I'm 
amazed - truly.", timestamp: "2019-03-19T00:00:00.000Z", Author: 
{…}, …}
11: {id: "cju980jdy01lo0740mmo1yfkf", name: "DiS iS TrASSh", text: 
"Thank u, next!", timestamp: "2019-01-12T00:00:00.000Z", Author: 
{…}, …}
12: {id: "cju980jev01lw0740p6k8r7d3", name: "Teach Me How to Do 
This!", text: "Notice me senpai", timestamp: "2019-02- 
19T00:00:00.000Z", Author: {…}, …}
13: {id: "cju980jfs01m40740pe5gxn9a", name: "This is nice", text: 
"...real nice", timestamp: "2019-01-11T00:00:00.000Z", Author: {…}, 
…}
14: {id: "cju980jge01mc0740mqyu5zi3", name: "Noob", text: "Why are 
you even posting a tutorial about something you know nothing 
about?", timestamp: "2018-07-14T00:00:00.000Z", Author: {…}, …}
15: {id: "cju980jgx01mk0740g1ehxjsf", name: "Wow", text: "You gotta 
create more of these.", timestamp: "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z", 
Author: {…}, …}
```

Comment: Please don't copy pase from console. Give short and real data(not from console);

Comment: this is on the state in React where I am setting this array to state, we are using GraphQL. Not sure what you would like me to post, please elaborate on your quest kindly,

Comment: I mean that your data is not readable. Kindly add data which we can test on and read easily. You can use `JSON.stringify()` on data and paste here.

Answer (score 0):

This will filter it out by `id`:

```js
const arr = [{
    Author: {
      id: "cju9808n401fo0740rbqgej9p",
      username: "asdfsd",
      email: "asldkf@gmail.com",
      __typename: "User"
    },
    ProjectReviewed: {
      id: "cju980j9a01kd07407qvtwh5o",
      name: "Amy's 1st ,Project ",
      titleImg: ",http: //lorempixel.com/400/400/",
      __typename: "Project"
    },
    id: "cju980jb901l00740i07skgpc",
    name: "Nice Job!",
    text: "I really like how you did this.",
    timestamp: "2019-04-05T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    Author: {
      id: "cju9808n401fo0740rbqgej9p",
      username: "asdfsd",
      email: "asldkf@gmail.com",
      __typename: "User"
    },
    ProjectReviewed: {
      id: "cju980j9a01kd07407qvtwh5o",
      name: "Amy's 1st ,Project ",
      titleImg: ",http: //lorempixel.com/400/400/",
      __typename: "Project"
    },
    id: "1cju980jb901l00740i07skgpc",
    name: "Nice Job!",
    text: "I really like how you did this.",
    timestamp: "2019-04-05T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
];
const matchId = 'cju980jb901l00740i07skgpc';
let res = arr.filter(({
  id
}) => id === matchId);
console.log(res);
```